# Cannot login to SQL Server after upgrade from version 2012 to version 2014

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have recently upgraded my SQL Server from version 2012 to version 2014.
During the installation process everything went fine and was successful.

After installation is complete, however, I can not login using `SA` account and password.

I have checked the `MSSQLSERVER` service and tried to run it manually but I get the error shown in this screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the eventvwr say ?

Comment: honestly i have not used Evntvwr before, i tried it, to find reason there but no idea how to use it to find MSSQLSERVER event and reason for not being runed.

Comment: windows +r and then type eventvwr,further review installation log file,it seems installation is not successfull

Comment: Although i could not find the Installation log file, i am sure there was nothing wrong with upgrade/installation. So, i checked the eventvwr, i found an error with "Report Server Windows Service (MSSQLSERVER): cannot connect to the report server database.". Then i restarted the service "Report Server Windows Service (MSSQLSERVER)", and this solved issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out to solve the issue below are the steps how i did it:

1. First checked the eventviewer in windows, and found the error related to MSSQLSERVER.
2. Then double clicked on it to find more details on this error.
3. When found out, it is related to SQL server Report service, when to services, and restarted it manually. and it solved my issue. (You may need to restart your PC too)[image]

[image]

[image]